# Bash command history not working

Tags: command-line, bash, history, guake

The command history between sessions is not getting saved. I'm using guake and the history for the session is working fine.

I noticed that **.bash_history** had some commands I executed in `sudo -s` mode and tried the same again and all the commands while in the session got saved so I tried:

```
chmod 777 .bash_history
```

Now the old commands appear at the start of a session but no new commands are getting saved.

Comment: So... what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  You dont seem to be asking a question here :/

Comment: Mode 777 is unnecessary, it has especially nothing to do with the 'executable' flag (the default mode is 600).

The `~/.bash_history` gets written when you log out (to reach the *newer* commands you can use the `history` command).

But i fail to see the problem too..

Answer (score 20):

The commands are not visible because Bash saves history to the .bash_history file only after the shell quits, and this happens very rarely with Guake. There is [a simple workaround](http://www.cuberick.com/2008/11/update-bash-history-in-realtime.html) to make Bash append the history (instead of overwriting the file) after every command

```
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: Pure awesome.  Wish I had known about this 5 years ago.

Comment: Link is down now. Should this be put in ~/.bashrc?

Answer (score 9):

Related, typically how this gets broken is if you sudo a command before you have a .bash_history file, as then it'll get created owned by root instead of your user.

Answer (score 3):

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/088 for how to avoid losing history lines, and an explanation of the side-effects of doing so.

Answer (score 3):

It could also be that root:root owns your .bash_history (ROOT SHOULDN'T BE THE OWNER, YOUR USER SHOULD BE THE OWNER!), in that case you need to:

```
#chown user:user .bash_history
```

This apparently could happen if you do `sudo bash` alot!